# Android actionbar: Custom fade animation on tab icon and title

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a custom animation that works pretty much the same way the tumblr android app works using the standard actionbar. (Not fading of the content of the tabs) I'm pretty close to getting it working but I have troubles fixing the last part. Maybe someone here can help me in the right direction to get this working.

EDIT: Image to show what I mean: [IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/nrzg3bbv9/b56b7766/)

What I have.

In onCreate I add some custom views for the tabs:

```
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    final CustomPageTransformer cpt = new CustomPageTransformer();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            cpt.currentItem = position;
        }
    });
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, cpt);

    CustomTabView tabNews = new CustomTabView(this, mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(0).toString(), mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(0));
    CustomTabView tabEvents = new CustomTabView(this, mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(1).toString(), mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(1));
    CustomTabView tabContacts = new CustomTabView(this, mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(2).toString(), mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(2));
    CustomTabView tabClub = new CustomTabView(this, mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(3).toString(), mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(3));

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabNews).setTabListener(this).setTag(0));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabEvents).setTabListener(this).setTag(1));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabContacts).setTabListener(this).setTag(2));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabClub).setTabListener(this).setTag(3));
```

The CustomTabView looks like this, where I've added two custom view so I can easily set the alpha of the views:

```
public class CustomTabView extends RelativeLayout {

AlphaTextView text1;
AlphaImageView icon1;
int alpha;

public CustomTabView(Context context, String text, Drawable icon) {
    super(context);
    init(context, text, icon);
}

public CustomTabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, null, null);     
}

public CustomTabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);    
    init(context, null, null);
}

private void init(Context context, String text, Drawable icon) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, this, true);

    text1 = (AlphaTextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    text1.setTypeface(Font.rMedium(context));
    text1.setText(text);

    icon1 = (AlphaImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon1.setImageDrawable(icon);

    setTheAlpha(128);
}

public void setTheAlpha(int aleph) {
    this.alpha = aleph;
    if (alpha < 128) alpha = 128;
    if (alpha > 255) alpha = 255;
    text1.onSetAlpha(alpha);
    icon1.onSetAlpha(alpha);
}

public int getTheAlpha() {
    return alpha;
}
}
```

Then there is the problem, the CustomPageTransformer:

```
public class CustomPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

public int currentItem = 0;
View currentView = null;

public CustomTabView tabNews = null;
public CustomTabView tabEvents = null;
public CustomTabView tabContacts = null;
public CustomTabView tabClub = null;

@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

    if (position != 0.0 && position != 1.0 && position != 2.0 && position != -1.0) {
        if (currentView == null) {
            currentView = view;
            Log.e("First number", String.valueOf(position));
        }
    } else if (position == 0.0 || position == 1.0 || position == 2.0 || position == -1.0 || position == -2.0) currentView = null;

    if (view == currentView) {
        int alphaCurrent = (int) (255 - (128*Math.abs(position)));
        if (alphaCurrent > 255) alphaCurrent = 255;
        else if (alphaCurrent < 128) alphaCurrent = 128;

        int alphaNext = (int) (128 + (128*Math.abs(position)));
        if (alphaNext > 255) alphaNext = 255;
        else if (alphaNext < 128) alphaNext = 128;

        if (tabNews != null && tabEvents != null && tabContacts != null && tabClub != null) {
            switch(currentItem) {
            case 0:
                if (position <= -1) {
                    tabNews.setTheAlpha(128);
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(255);

                } else if (position <= 0) {
                    tabNews.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (position <= -1) {
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(128);
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(255);

                } else if (position <= 0) {
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);

                } else if (position <= 1) {
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tabNews.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);

                } else if (position > 1) {
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(128);
                    tabNews.setTheAlpha(255);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (position <= -1) {
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(128);
                    tabClub.setTheAlpha(255);

                } else if (position <= 0) {
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tabClub.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);

                } else if (position <= 1) {
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);

                } else if (position > 1) {
                    tabEvents.setTheAlpha(255);
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(128);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (position <= 1) {
                    tabClub.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);

                } else if (position > 1) {
                    tabClub.setTheAlpha(128);
                    tabContacts.setTheAlpha(255);
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

The [transformPage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) method gets (View & Position). The view is always the fragment you are going to and from in the viewpager, so every second time I have a positive value in position and then the next a negative value depending on which direction you are sliding.

First I thought I could use the view to determine which the current tab is and what direction I'm going in by taking whatever view comes first, but that seems to be random.

And since the position value jumps from negative to positive it generates a bit of a random fading result in the tabs.

Any ideas of how I can get this to work smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better way of achieving this without using the page transformer. By using setOnPageChangeListener.

I've made an example app here: https://github.com/andreborud/FadingTabs

The code is pretty much just this:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int alphaCurrent = (int) (255 - (128*Math.abs(positionOffset)));
        int alphaNext = (int) (128 + (128*Math.abs(positionOffset)));
        if (positionOffset != 0) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0: 
                    tab0.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tab1.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tab1.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tab2.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tab2.setTheAlpha(alphaCurrent);
                    tab3.setTheAlpha(alphaNext);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I still need to compile any gradle for this? Or this is just a sample. :)